# display flex not working when resizing the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, responsive

If screen width is less than 800px then I want to hide my navigation links and a fas fa bar button will show up . Clicking on that button I will make navigation links display : grid (or none alternatively) . The problem is  -- After that if I am resizing my screen to greater than 800px width , navigation links are not changing to display : flex.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    body {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
    nav ul{
        display: none;
    }
    .nav-toggle{
        display: inline-block;
    }
   }
 @media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
        body {
            background-color: black;
          }
        nav ul{
            display: flex;
        }
    }
```

in Js file , I have this

```
let navToggle = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-toggle")[0];
let navLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("links")[0];
navToggle.addEventListener('click',showlinks);
function showlinks(){
    if(navLinks.style.display == "grid")
    navLinks.style.display = "none";
  else
    if(navLinks.style.display = "none")
    navLinks.style.display = "grid";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create element with class sidebar first. Let it be fixed on top using this code:

```
.sidebar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Next create a button that when clicked will show the div. Give it whatever style you want:

```
<input type="button" value="Show Sidebar" onclick="showsidebar()" class="showbutton" style="display:none;">
```

Now you want that at less than 800px it be reduced to sidebar:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    display:none;
  }
  .showbutton{
    display:block;
  }
}
```

Now add a javascript function that when the button is clicked your sidebar will be shown:

```
function showsidebar(){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar");
    x.style.display="block";
}
```